# preg_match PHP length and numerical

Tags: php, preg-match, credit-card, numerical

I'm creating a dummy payment page and checking if the credit card is 16 digits exactly in length and numerical only.

The problem is: If the credit card number is numerical and under 16digits it echo's ccno length, but also if the credit card number is valid (numerical and 16digits) it also echo's "ccno length".

```
 if (!preg_match("/^[0-9]{16}$/", $ccno)) {
       echo "ccno length";
     exit ();
  }
```

Thanks!

Comment: Code works fine for 16-digits card nums and doesn't echo anything, for other nums it echo `ccno length`. Check it once again.

Comment: You could just as easily do `strleng($ccno) && is_numerical($ccno)`. Also note there are already ways to determine valid credit numbers.

Comment: @JaredFarrish: The problem with this approach is that `is_numeric` returns true for a string with a decimal number.

Comment: `is_numeric` would indeed by a poor choice here, but [`ctype_digit()`](http://php.net/ctype_digit) would be perfect.

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte - Yes, I was a bit premature. [`if ((int) $ccno != $ccno || strlen($ccno) !== 16)`](http://codepad.viper-7.com/XPCRGJ)

Comment: Your code appears to work fine for me; maybe `$ccno` doesn't contain what you think it does. [Here's a demo showing the check working OK](http://codepad.viper-7.com/PAgWUR).

Comment: have tried this and it still doesnt work: if ((strlen($ccno) == 16) && is_digits($ccno)){
echo "good";
exit();
}

Comment: @CJava: the reason is that `is_int` returns true only for a int type and returns false for a string.

Comment: @CJava What is `is_digits`?

Comment: @IMSoP that checks its numerical without decimal places. the strlen returns 0 when its 16digits

Comment: @CJava My point was that it's not a built-in PHP function, so we have no way of seeing if it works or not. However, to reiterate **the code you've posted here [works fine](http://php.net/ctype_digit)**, even if it's not the best approach. The bug lies elsewhere in your code. Try `var_dump($ccno)` to see what value it actually has.